# How to publish an update on Google Play for just one country

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

We have an app available on Google Play for the whole world. Now we want to try our update for just one country before we make it available for the whole world.

I got the information that it's not possible to make an update available just for one country and have the old version available for the rest of the world. Is this true and if not how is it done? If it's not a feature on Google Play is there any other smart way to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: I dont think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this true and if not how is it done?

Yes it is true that you can not release update of an application to one country if your application is already running in all countries.

Google Play does not support this which you are looking.

Comment: Any idea if this is still true or not?